# Finding an organization's public social media profiles via Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-knowledge-graph

When you search for a brand or organization in Google, you often get an info block like this:

[image]

From some research, I've determined that this information comes from the Google Knowledge Graph API. However, if I search for that brand or organization, I don't get the social media information.

Potentially, this information can appear under the `url.sameAs` field of any entity (of type [Thing](https://schema.org/Thing)). However, when I make a query to the Google Knowedge Graph API, I do not receive this information:

```
GET https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?prefix=true&query=Bezeq&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Yields:

```
"@type": "EntitySearchResult",
 "result": {
  "@id": "kg:/m/01tjk8",
  "name": "Bezeq",
  "@type": [
   "Corporation",
   "Thing",
   "Organization"
  ],
  "description": "Telecommunications company",
  "image": {
   "contentUrl": "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRybGXwH0QomTkKsrK_Klilh6Pcuj9WS0tqrO_DgBkyX6NbEsvR",
   "url": "https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%96%D7%A7",
   "license": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0"
  },
  "detailedDescription": {
   "articleBody": "Bezeq is the largest telecommunications group in Israel. Bezeq and its subsidiaries offer a range of telecom services, including fixed-line, mobile telephony, high-speed Internet, transmission, and pay TV.",
   "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezeq",
   "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
  },
  "url": "http://www.bezeq.co.il/"
 },
 "resultScore": 43.007484
},
```

I've also attempted to look for the information using the Google Places API, but it wasn't there either.

Is this information accessible via the API? If so, where and how do I access it?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: @SamLittlefair Not really. I think I reached the conclusion that the social media profiles were hidden on purpose to prevent harvesting and the like. I sent several requests to Google for information but they didn&#39;t answer me.

Answer (score 3):

The social profile information is not accessible via the API (see the API response specification [here](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/)) and there is no indication yet that this is going to change.